# C# Skype bot (Skype4com) Windows Service

Tags: c#, skype

I've been working on a Skype bot program.

The idea is the when the user sends messages to the bot with certain keywords it will provide the results of a SQL script that is run in the background.

I've been able to get it to work as a Windows console app , but I'm trying to convert it into a Windows service.

I've tried using Top Shelf and the Visual Studio Windows service template, both are not working. I'm able to install the Windows service, but when I try to run it it fails.

I keep getting this error

> Service cannot be started. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x80040200): Not attached.    at SKYPE4COMLib.ISkype.Attach(Int32
>   Protocol, Boolean Wait)

This happens as soon as the program tries to attach its self to Skype.

> skype.Attach(7, true);

I've come to the conclusion that the Windows service and Skype are on different levels and cant see each other. I've seen other Stack Overflow questions that came back with the same results.

I was was wondering is there any way to change this or is it impossible?

Comment: Actually i hate spam bots. They sent me also messages if i write back. :-)

Comment: I could see that, but this spam bot will be used for good (also by my team to make our job easier).

Comment: @AaronBerndt - are you sure the skype client and the windows service are running under the same credentials?

Comment: @KnightFox - Yes, at least i'm pretty sure. I've tried running the windows services as Local System, Network Service, Local Service, and using my own creds on my machine. None of them worked.

Comment: Did you grant "allow service to interact with desktop" rights? I'm assuming the machine stays logged in with a skype client.

Comment: @LSU.Net I thought that setting didn't do anything in Windows 7 (and maybe Vista)?

Comment: You're right, @KennethK.

Comment: Here's an article I found on creating a service which starts a scheduled task (which can interact with the desktop). http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110568/Alternative-way-for-Window-services-to-interact-wi

Comment: @KennethK - I did try that before learning that it didn't do anything.

Comment: @LSU.Net - Thanks I will look into that and see if it works.

Comment: @LSU.Net  - I tried the link it still gets the same error.